# How to select only parent elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select only parent elements but it's not work corrrectly(or I don't do properly.) How to select only parent elements?

```css
body > ul > li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent
      <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: @SuperDJ how it's a duplicate? because it contains the word *parent*?

Comment: @TemaniAfif letting them know there is no parent selector in CSS

Comment: @SuperDJ but the question has nothing to do with *parent selector*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing the **inheritance** behavior. You are setting the color to only the parent but child are inheriting this color too.

[image]

You need to reset the style for child:

```css
body > ul > li {
  color: green;
}
body > ul > li > ul {
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent
      <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `<ul>` takes css from parent. You need to overwrite this

```css
body > ul > li {
  color: green;
}

body > ul > li ul {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent
      <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: What makes 'black' appropriate?

Comment: @PeterB Death Metal. It's just illustration of color reset. I don't know what OP is using by default.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body > ul > li {
  color: green;
}

body > ul > li > ul {
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent
      <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent</li>
    <li>parent</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
body  ul  li { color: green; }
```

Comment: Why use body everything is in the body anyway?

Comment: Wrong, and if you tried it you would have seen that it makes no difference.

Comment: It should work! Problem with you code is the way you query the selector